# Is this a bug in jQuery 1.9.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the jQuery 1.9.1 source, line 974 (the version I downloaded) reads:

```
while ((i = o.handlers[a++]) && !e.isImmediatePropagationStopped())(!e.namespace_re || e.namespace_re.test(i.namespace)) && (e.handleObj = i, e.data = i.data, r = ((b.event.special[i.origType] || {}).handle || i.handler).apply(o.elem, u), r !== t && (e.result = r) === !1 && (e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation()))
```

It's a monstrosity of a line...

I'm getting an error as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ((b.event.special[i.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || i.handler).apply is not a functionb.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.9.1.js:974
b.event.add.v.handle @ jquery-1.9.1.js:914
b.event.trigger @ jquery-1.9.1.js:953
b.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.9.1.js:2796
(anonymous function) @ tech_payments.js:39
b.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.9.1.js:974
b.event.add.v.handle @ jquery-1.9.1.js:914
```

And when I set a breakpoint at line 974 in that file and check out what the various vars get set to I see the following:

[image: Scope]

You can see that 'o' is a thing, and that o.handlers[a++] works as well:

[image]

But for whatever reason, inside the brackets inside the while loop, i isn't being assigned to o.handlers[0] or anything else.

Is this a bug in jQuery 1.9.1 with order of evaluation or something?  I'm totally lost on this one.

UPDATE:

I stumbled randomly on what was causing the issue:

```
//      /*
    //       * Registers a callback which copies the csrf token into the
    //       * X-CSRF-Token header with each ajax request.  Necessary to
    //       * work with rails applications which have fixed
    //       * CVE-2011-0447
    //       */
    //
    $(document).ajaxSend({
      onCreate: function(request) {
        var csrf_meta_tag = $$('meta[name=csrf-token]')[0];

        if (csrf_meta_tag) {
          var header = 'X-CSRF-Token',
              token  = csrf_meta_tag.readAttribute('content');

          if (!request.options.requestHeaders) {
            request.options.requestHeaders = {};
          }
          request.options.requestHeaders[header] = token;
        }
      }
    });
```

jQuery Mobile was having a problem losing the session on ajaxSend, and a solution I came across on this site suggested the above.  There are a variety of fixes with some variation of the above, and I tried a few of them until I got the one that works AND doesn't break my other Ajax.

All I can say is that:

1. The problem is gone
2. I am no JS wizard
3. I have no idea why adding a static header to an ajax request breaks jQuery

Comment: What is the context for this exception? maybe it's something your code does that "has a bug"

Comment: I highly doubt that the problem is in jQuery, most likely you are handing jQuery something it doesn't expect. What does *your* code look like?

Comment: `|| {}).handle` looks kinda suspect... an empty object that doesn't have a `handle` property isn't going to have a handle property that contains something with an apply method.

Comment: Ah, it would become i.handler due to the next `||`. wish i could find the source for this in github.